# Convert UTC date to milliseconds JavaScript

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, time, momentjs

I need to compare two dates in my React Native app: current date with the server one in UTC format. What's the best approach here?

I thought about converting two dates into milliseconds and then converting them.

Example:

`2019-06-20T14:26:58Z` - milliseconds

`current date` - milliseconds

So, what is the best approach here?

It's React Native, so it should work without connected chrome debugger.

Comment: Modern ECMAScript implementations will parse 2019-06-20T14:26:58Z natively, however older browsers may not. See [*Why does Date.parse give incorrect results?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587345/why-does-date-parse-give-incorrect-results)

Answer (score 0):

The momentjs query API has several useful methods for comparing dates. Here's an example of the `isSame` method. There are others including `isSameOrBefore`, `isAfter`, `isSameOrAfter` to name a few.

```
// convert current date to UTC
const currentDateUtc = moment(currentDate).utc();

// check if current date is the same as the server date
currentDateUtc.isSame(moment(serverDate).utc())
```

Read more about [moment's query API](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/) in their docs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Date.getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

```js
const serverTime = new Date('2019-06-20T14:26:58Z')
const currentTime = new Date()

console.log({
  serverTime: {
    milliseconds: serverTime.getTime(),
    toString: serverTime.toString()
  }
})

console.log({
  currentTime: {
    milliseconds: currentTime.getTime(),
    toString: currentTime.toString()
  }
})

console.log(serverTime.getTime() < currentTime.getTime())
```